# Can you get the exact real value of $ \left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{89}-\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{91}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

By using euler formula,one can obtain:
$$
2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)=\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{89}-\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{91}.
$$
In order to get the exact real value of 
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right),
$$
Can you  get the exact real value of 
$$
\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{89}-\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{91}?
$$

Comment: One needs a definition of $(-1)^{1/n}$ before the question makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by the "exact real value"? What's not exact about $\sin(\pi/180)$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\large
(-1)^{\frac1{180}} = e^{-j\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{180}}
$$
$$\large
\begin{align}
((-1)^{\frac1{180}})^{89} - ((-1)^{\frac1{180}})^{91}
&=e^{-j\frac{(\pi+2k\pi)(90-1)}{180}} - e^{-j\frac{(\pi+2k\pi)(90+1)}{180}} \\
&= 2je^{-j\frac{(\pi+2k\pi)(90)}{180}}\sin\frac{(\pi+2k\pi)}{180}\\
&= 2(-1)^k\sin\frac{(\pi+2k\pi)}{180}  , \quad k=0,1,\cdots,179\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Because $$2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right) = \left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{89} - \left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{91}$$ and $$2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)$$ is a real number, there must be a real number $x$ satisfies $$ x=\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{89}-\left((-1)^{\frac{1}{180}}\right)^{91}. $$

Comment: Just visibly, it is obviously real.  Working visibly makes it easy to see the answer.  Trig on a circle...

Comment: @ex0du5 $(-1)^{\frac12}$ is visibly! real too!!!

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Roots of unity are points symmetrically arranged on a circle.  Nth roots are points on a n-gon on that circle which include 1.  Here, we are looking at 360-gon.  By symmetry, points 89 and 91 are just to the right and left of i, slightly down at the same imaginary value.  Subtracting gives the length of the line between them, which is parallel to real and clearly real as a vector.  You can get the sine formula by building triangles, as in high school geometry.

Comment: @ex0du5 Thanks. If my answer is not correct, please write a correct one.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi, I think the answer is correct but perhaps the way to get it is a little blurry (among other things, because of the physics' use of $\;j\;$ of what we mathematicians call $\;i\;$)...but I think it's fine.+1

Comment: @DonAntonio: it was incorrect when it said the answer was pure imaginary.  That has been edited away now, making the first few of us responding not quite as understandable.  No one disagreed with the sine formula, which is in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's probably easier to find $\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$ by other means. To wit:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}5\right) & = & \sqrt{\frac58 - \frac{\sqrt5}8}
\end{eqnarray}$$

and then use double- and triple-angle formulae.

Comment: Wouldn't you need half/third angle formulae, which would be much less simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following approach:

$$-1=e^{\pi i+2k\pi i}=e^{\pi i(2k+1)}\;,\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies (-1)^{1/180}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{180}(2k+1)}$$

and from here

$$\left((-1)^{1/180}\right)^{89}-\left((-1)^{1/180}\right)^{91}=\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{180}(2k+1)}\right)^{89}-\left(e^{\frac{\pi i}{180}(2k+1)}\right)^{91}=$$

$$=e^{\frac{89\pi i}{180}(2k+1)}\left(1-e^{\frac{\pi i}{90}(2k+1)}\right)$$

Taking the real part of the above we get

$$\cos\frac{89\pi (2k+1)}{180}\left(1-\cos\frac{\pi (2k+1)}{90}\right)+\sin\frac{89\pi (2k+1)}{180}\sin\frac{\pi (2k+1)}{90}=$$

$$=\cos\frac{89\pi (2k+1)}{180}-\cos\frac{91\pi (2k+1)}{180}=2\sin\pi (2k+1)\cdot\sin\frac{2\pi (2k+1)}{90}=0$$

The equality one before the last above follows from the trigonometric identity

$$\cos x-\cos y=-2\sin\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2$$